# Need help in using bsxfun

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have two arrays in MATLAB:

```
A; % size(A) = [NX NY NZ 3 3]
b; % size(b) = [NX NY NZ 3 1]
```

In fact, in the three dimensional domain, I have two arrays defined for each `(i, j, k)` which are obtained from above-mentioned arrays `A` and `b`, respectively and their sizes are `[3 3]` and `[3 1]`, respectively. Let's for the sake of example, call these arrays `m` and `n`.

```
m; % size(m) = [3 3]
n; % size(n) = [3 1]
```

How can I solve `m\n` for each point of the domain in a *vectorize fashion*? I used `bsxfun` but I am not successful.

```
solution = bsxfun( @(A,b) A\b, A, b );
```

I think the problem is with the expansion of the singleton elements and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `bsxfun` isn't the right thing to use here.  `arrayfun` would be better, if you could tell it to only iterate the first 3 dimensions.  What's wrong with loops?  These problems are all completely independent.

Comment: I thought about `arrayfun` but I could not figure out how to iterate over the first dimensions. I want to avoid loops as the arrays that I have are very big.

Comment: To iterate only over one dimension, a reshape to '[NX*NY*NZ 3 3]' / '[NX*NY*NZ 3 1]' could simplify it.

Comment: @Daniel: Do you mean `A = reshape(A(:), [NY*NY*NZ 3 3])` and `b = reshape(b(:), [NX*NY*NZ 3 1])`?

Comment: @Divakar: I tried it in the folowing example and I did not get the correct answer. `A = rand(10,10,10,3,3); b = pi*ones(10,10,10,3); x = permute(permute(A(:,:,:,1,:),[1 2 3 5 4]).\b,[1 2 3 5 4]);`. Here is the result of the comparison: `i=1; j=1; k=1; AA = squeeze(A(i, j, k, :, :)), bb = squeeze(b(i, j, k, :)), xx = AA\bb, squeeze(x(i, j, k, :))`.

Comment: @A2009 Yes you are solving matrices there, which I didn't take into account. Now `bsxfun` doesn't have that, so you have to try some other thing most probably.

Comment: @A2009 I believe `solution = A./b ` should work just fine

Comment: @Nishant: No it won't.  @A2009 wants the least squares solution for each pair of `m` and `n`.  What you are doing is simply a point by point division.

Comment: `arrayfun` or nested `for` loops are probably the way to go here I can't see a way to get `bsxfun` to do this effectively... for arrayfun you would need grids of i,j,k values (probably best made with `ndgrid`) and a function for example based on your previous comment `@(ii,jj,kk)squeeze(A(ii,jj,kk,:,:))\squeeze(b(ii,jj,kk,:))`

Comment: @RTL: Could you show me how I should do it using `arrayfun`? I am getting an error because `A` and `b` are not the same sizes: `[NX NY NZ 3 3]` and `[NX NY NZ 3 1]` and `arrayfun` complains about this. `[i, j, k ] = ndgrid(1:NX, 1:NY, 1:NZ);`, `solution = arrayfun( @(i, j, k, A, b) squeeze(A(i,j,k,:,:))\squeeze(b(i,j,k,:)), i(:), j(:), k(:), A, b);`

Comment: ok... take A and b out of the arguments for both the anonymous function and arrayfun, leave them in the actual 'function part' of the anonymous function. The 3 grids shouldn't need `(:)` after, also the function returns a vector so add `'UniformOutput',false` to the end of the arguments for arrayfun.  Finally depending in the sizes of NX,NY and NZ it may be better to go with for loops, arrayfun isn't always faster (however for NX,NY,NZ=10 as above comment it probably will be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried some solutions, it seems that a for loop is acutally the fastest possibility in this case.

A naive approach looks like this:

```
%iterate
C=zeros(size(B));
for a=1:size(A,1)
    for b=1:size(A,2)
        for c=1:size(A,3)
            C(a,b,c,:)=squeeze(A(a,b,c,:,:))\squeeze(B(a,b,c,:));
        end
    end
end
```

The squeeze is expensive in computation time, because it needs some advanced indexing. Swapping the dimensions instead is faster.

```
A=permute(A,[4,5,1,2,3]);
B=permute(B,[4,1,2,3]);
C2=zeros(size(B));
for a=1:size(A,3)
    for b=1:size(A,4)
        for c=1:size(A,5)
            C2(:,a,b,c)=(A(:,:,a,b,c))\(B(:,a,b,c));
        end
    end
end
C2=permute(C2,[2,3,4,1]);
```

The second solution is about 5 times faster.

/Update: I found an improved version. Reshaping and using only one large loop increases the speed again. This version is also suitable to be used with the parallel computing toolbox, in case you own it replace the for with a parfor and start the workers.

```
A=permute(A,[4,5,1,2,3]);
B=permute(B,[4,1,2,3]);
%linearize A and B to get a better performance
linA=reshape(A,[size(A,1),size(A,2),size(A,3)*size(A,4)*size(A,5)]);
linB=reshape(B,[size(B,1),size(B,2)*size(B,3)*size(B,4)]);
C3=zeros(size(linB));
for a=1:size(linA,3)
    C3(:,a)=(linA(:,:,a))\(linB(:,a));
end
%undo linearization
C3=reshape(C3,size(B));
%undo dimension swap
C3=permute(C3,[2,3,4,1]);
```